# The package it.devapp collides with a type

Tags: java, android, package

I'm trying to code in Android for the intents but I continue to have the same error. The package collides with a type. I tried to clean but nothing happened.

Here is my code

```
package android.app.Activity;
package it.devapp;

import android.app.Activity;

public class MainActivity extends Activity{
    public class MainActivity extends ListActivity{

        protected void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
            setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, new String[] { "http://developer.android.com", "http://www.devapp.it"}));
        }
    }
}
```

The error is on the second line.

Comment: The error is it.devapp sorry for the indentation

Comment: You declared 2 packages. Try removing the one you don't use (i.e. `package android.app.Activity;`). Also, remove the outer `MainActivity` class.

Comment: Ok I tried to eliminate the package and I notice that in the Manifest there isn't the error. I have it only in the MainActivity and in the Web view. Here is my effective code

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/9446942

Comment: Umm.. okay.. I don't see any issue with your code on gist? Or are you still having the same error?

Comment: I have the same error but I changed the code. Always "The package it.devapp collides with a type"

Comment: Chicca94, can you post your updated code? I cannot see it in the gist.